# How can I efficiently do master/detail grouping in Linq from a flat enumerable where there is no hard link from master to detail?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a flat enumerable of strings with a master record identified based on some criteria (in this example an integer), followed by any number of detailed records.  There is no hard tie from a detail to its master - the only tie is that the position of the master record precedes its detail records.

I have created a Linq query that gets me the results I want, but I would prefer not to do the `SkipWhile()` and `TakeWhile()` calls if possible.  It feels very inefficient, especially since I could do this query as a simple foreach loop at O(n).

Here's an mock example that returns the results I want, just not as efficiently as I'd like:

```
var data = new[] {"1", "a", "b", "c", "2", "d", "e", "3", "1", "f", "g", "h", "i", "2", "j", "k", "l"};
int throwAway;

var indexedData = data.Select((item, index) => new {item, index} );

var results =
    from a in indexedData
    where Int32.TryParse(a.item, out throwAway) == true
    select new {
        HeaderIndex = a.index,
        HeaderValue = a.item,
        Details = 
            indexedData
            .SkipWhile((x) => x.index <= a.index)
            .TakeWhile(x => Int32.TryParse(x.item, out throwAway) == false)
            .Select(x => x.item)
    };

results.Dump();
```

[image: Desired LinqPad Results]

Is there a way to do this query in Linq more efficiently without resorting to a traditional loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a helper function that can group items while a condition is met:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (predicate(iterator.Current))
            {
                list.Add(iterator.Current);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };
            }
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Then, since LINQ just doesn't play as nice with `out` params we can make a non-out version of `TryParse`:

```
public static bool IsInt(string value)
{
    int num;
    return int.TryParse(value, out num);
}
```

Using this we can get the group of items that are not numbers:

```
data.GroupWhile(str => !IsInt(str))
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Number = group.First(),
        Letters = group.Skip(1),
    });
```

Adding the indexes back in and validating invalid input data is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

you can use some string manipulation to turn this into a handful of lines of code:

```
int idx = 0, loser;
var results = data
    // turn the list of strings into one string, where we separate the groups by a delimiter
    // and the elements in the group by a different delimiter
    .Aggregate((soFar, next) => int.TryParse(next, out loser) ? soFar + "|" + next : soFar + '=' + next)
    // split by that delimiter, to get the groups
    .Split('|')
    .Select(s =>
    {
        // get the elements in the group split up
        var groupValues = s.Split('=');
        // create the resulting object, using the index
        var r = new { HeaderIndex = idx, HeaderValue = int.Parse(groupValues[0]), Details = groupValues.Skip(1).ToList() };
        // update the index
        idx += s.Length;
        return r;
    });
```

this returns the requested data, but the `Details` are a `List<string>`, not just an `Enumerable<string>`

Comment: That's a very creative solution.  Unfortunately, my example data was a little contrived.  The actual master/detail records will be quite a few variable bytes long rather than just a single dependable string character.

Comment: @mattmc3 I realized I made some assumptions, but that shouldn't stop you :P I'll edit the code to make it work for random-length strings, not just chars.